# Transformation between Ideal and Warped Surface

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I work on manufacturing metal panels with holes drilled in them. Suppose I have an ideal 3D surface from CAD. I want to compare it to the actual part using reference points to compare between the two. Ideally yielding some sort of function that when given a point on the mathematically ideal 3D surface, be able to output the correct location on the real surface. Question is where do I start?

I was thinking 3D homography but not seeing a much on a complex surface. This issue is further complicated by manufacturing tolerances of the reference points on the real part.